# React Native Local Notification - OnNotification not firing when oneSignal is integrated

Tags: ios, react-native, onesignal, react-native-push-notification

In our app we now requires to show a Local Notification.  Local Notification appears correctly, but when we click on the Notification nothing is happening. After our research we found that when we are using Local Notification along with OneSignal Library the below function in ‘App Delegate’ is not getting fired.

```
// Required for the localNotification event.
 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
 {
  [RCTPushNotificationManager didReceiveLocalNotification:notification];
 }
```

I have tried uninstalling the OneSignal and then the above function gets fired and we are able to do something when the user clicks on the Local Notification.

This issue is only on IOS. As OneSignal is not supporting LocalNotification please help us to understand why the above function is not getting fired when OneSignal is integrated. Or there are any other solutions.

We tried React-native-Push-Notification, PushNotificationIOS library etc but all behaves the same. Any help will be highly appreciated.